# Play mp3 file smoothly upon dragging a scroll using AVToolbox or openAL

Tags: iphone, ios4, audio, openal

I have been facing this since so many days but I have not reach to any conclusion.

My problem is : I want to play an mp3 file  but not simply by clicking on a play button.

It is this way I want to play it.

****There is a slider that I can drag using finger, I want that the mp3 should play with the frequency with which I am dragging the finger (or speed with which I am dragging my finger, so that it will give an effect of fast forwarding (funny type of voice)) or if I drag slider slowyly the output will be slow ****

The problem is the output of the sound is not coming out smooth. its very distorted and disturbed voice. 
I want the outuput to be smoother.

Please help. Any suggestions please. Presently I am using AVAudioPlayer and passing the time value based upon slider input to play the file. (It does not seems to be feasible though). 
I feel that it is possible using openAL only and no other way. Because using openAL we can modify the frequency of the sound file (pitch)

**CAN SOME ONE PLEASE REFER ME A LINK TO  openAL implementation for iPhone . I have never played a sound file using openAL**

Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with AVAudioPlayer, as it does not support pitch operations.

You can load and decode the entire track into memory for playback with OpenAL (which supports pitch), or you can do realtime loading/decoding and pitch changing using Audio Units (MUCH lower level, and more complicated, though).

Comment: ok. Can you please refer me  a link for openAL implementation in for iPhone. I have never implemented  playing a sound file using openAL. What I have come to know after researching that.  * I will need to change the pitch of the file that I am going to play ( Based upon the speed with which I am sliding the slider ), in this case, it will be little complicated as I am seeing it means I will need to dynamically change the rate at which sound data being processed. * help!!

Comment: I wrote an OpenAL wrapper library to make audio easier on iOS. Give it a try. https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone

Comment: Thanx  a million times. It really helped me out and now I can use this source code as I want. Lov you Karl ;)

Comment: (bool) preloadUrl:(NSURL*) url seekTime:(NSTimeInterval)seekTime;